# Open file limit on Ubuntu server

Tags: java, ubuntu-16.04, bitbucket-server

My Java Tomcat application (Bitbucket) is hosted on Ubuntu 16.04 and i will get below error when Open file limit exceeds.

```
java.io.IOException: Too many open file
```

i fixed the issue initially with adding below lines to  `/etc/security/limits.conf` file

```
atlbitbucket hard nofile 8192 
atlbitbucket soft nofile 4096
```

however issue recurred twice again:

1. Is there an upper limit for open files ?
2. how to monitor open files every 1 minutes and log it to plot a graph?
3. how to mitigate Open file limit issues to avoid above error?

Answer (score 0):

1) Linux does have an upper bound limit which is, usually, sufficient (if that's what you asked). Still, for bitbucket you can set:

```
atlbitbucket hard nofile unlimited
atlbitbucket soft nofile unlimited
```

2) Use the [`watch`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/watch) command to count the opened files every 1 minute:

```
watch -n 60 ls -l /proc/$$/fd | wc -l
```

where $$ is the PID of bitbucket process. It's not a graph, but you'll have a pretty clear idea what's going on.

3) See 1)

Comment: Thank you , the command : watch -n 5 'ls -l /proc/123731/fd | wc -l' worked for me on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Comment: How can we calculate  ulimit for open files based on resources available on the server, is there any formula or it is by guess keep increasing the limit when we hit the max List of open files?

Comment: Got the answer from Redhat website.  256 for every 4MB of RAM.